# Why Emails are Not Received?

Tags: 2010

My simple Designer 2010 workflow correctly sends an email to one of my list permission groups. However, that group never receives the emails but my CC copy of the same email received shows all the groups email addresses in the TO field, as it should. The workflow history shows it processes correctly.

What could possibly be the cause?
Does giving unique permissions to the same email group cause an issue?

Comment: Test: Can 1 person receive the email if the 1 person is in the To: field?<br>
Also: Is there a way to check the mail server (exchange?) for a delivery failure? Note: I would rather have posted this in a comment instead of an "answer", I don't have enough rep points to leave a comment. Grrr.

Comment: Yes, I can enter a couple email addresses and it will send correctly but fails to send to the group.  I rebuilt the groups but still didn't work.  The emails are not going to junk, however, we have seen some issues with other workflows where the emails are getting hung up in SMTP or something like that.  Also, it's true that if I place identical emails in the TO and CC, only one is actually received, but that is not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This only happens to me when the user's SharePoint emails are going straight to junk or if they have a rule set up to re-route SharePoint emails from some other site that has a different display name but the same email address.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding it, you are emailing the same recipients in the To and CC fields.  Many email servers will only send one email when they see this.